# Can we track face emotional like happy, sad, angry in Spark AR?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

i am newbie for Spark AR. I just learn the basic, and i wanna now that can we track face emotional like sad, happy, angry etc? Like a facetracker using javascript made by [justadudewhohacks](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some Face Gestures that are supported by Spark such as happy, smiling, surprised, kissing, etc. See here:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/facegesturesmodule/